# PDFMiner corrupting some text

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I am using the following script to convert each page of a pdf to a file, but I am getting some weird cases where most of the text on the page is corrupted. Some pdfs come out perfect and others don't so I'm guessing there's a difference in how some are encoded, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what settings I can change in my script to account for this. Is it the codec I'm using?

```
# Python 3
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

def set_interpreter():
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    return { 'retstr': retstr, 'device': device, 'interpreter': interpreter }

si = set_interpreter()
retstr = si['retstr']
device = si['device']
interpreter = si['interpreter']

fp = open(path, 'rb')
password = ""
maxpages = 0
caching = True
pagenos=set()

for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    f = open(new_file, 'w') # Open file
    f.write(retstr.getvalue())
    f.close()
    si = set_interpreter()
    retstr = si['retstr']
    device = si['device']
    interpreter = si['interpreter']
```

Here is the start of the corrupted output showing the part that is correct which then changes back to being corrupted.

```
& -?í=

- 6AéCH=B | lunes 27 de junio del 2 011

-567,1

-+Í) 51,)41)

4AAI=I >== $
A A FHEAH JHEAIJHA

- BK @A ?=FEJ=AI ALE=@I FH I ECH=JAI A?K=JHE=I A I
FHEAHI JHAI AIAI @A AIJA =ñ BKA  ' EAI AI GKA @KH=JA A
?K=HJ JHEAIJHA @A   ,AI@A -IF=ñ= IA HAEJEAH   #'% EAI

?A ?KE@=@AI IA KA
F=H= =FHLA?D=H IK JKHEI


.
)
4
/
É

-
6


-

|

1


8
0
+
4
)

4A@=??Eó -?í=
A?í=(JAACH=B?A?

- BK @A HAAI=I B=EE=HAI FH
LAEAJAI @A -IF=ñ= -IJ=@I 7E
@I @A )éHE?= A 1J=E= @AI?A@Eó =
## EAI  GKA IECEBE?= K
$ EBAHEH = FHAIAJ=@ A A
?K=HJ JHEAIJHA @A    ##'
EAI O =OH A $$ ?
F=H=@ ? A FHEAH JHEAIJHA @A
   ##' EAI IACú K
EBHA @A = ,EHA??Eó @A -IJ=
@íIJE?=I -?óE?=I @A *=? +A
JH= @A -?K=@H *+-

- EI AIJK@E IAñ== GKA -I
F=ñ= -IJ=@I 7E@I A 1J=E= HA
FHAIAJ= A '!! @A BK JJ= @A
HAAI=I HA?E>E@ A A FHEAH JHE
AIJHA @A   - J JJ= A
LE=@ @AI@A AI=I =JEJK@AI IA K>E?ó
A I  #&'%

=I HAAI=I HA?E>E@=I @AI@A -I
F=ñ= A A FHEAH JHEAIJHA @A  
IK=H   #'% EAI ?JHE
>KOA@ ? A "" @A BK JJ=
A A F=íI ANFAHEAJ=@ K= @EI
EK?Eó @A   ?JA=@ ? A
?K=HJ JHEAIJHA @A     $!
EAI EAJH=I GKA ?F=H=@
? A FHEAH JHEAIJHA @A  
 '% EAI FHAIAJ= K =K
AJ @A & 

- AIJA EI FAHí@ -IJ=@I
7E@I HAEJEó = -?K=@H  !"
EAI GKA HAFHAIAJ= A !'%
@A J JJ= HA?E>E@ 1CK=A
JA = ?F=H=H AIJA L=H ? A
?K=HJ JHEAIJHA @A    "&#
EAI FHAIAJ= K= @EIEK?Eó
@A #' O IEE=H ?FHJ=EAJ


.
)
4
/
É

-
6


-

|

1


8
0
+
4
)

Los migrantes ecuatorianos en España siguen siendo los que más cantidad

de remesas envían anualmente, superando a los de EE.UU. e Italia.

IA >IAHL= F=H= A FHEAH JHEAIJHA
@A    "&  EAI ? K=
?JH=??Eó @A #%
```

And here is the page this instance occurs on.
[image: PDF Page]
As a note, there are other pdfs that are able to be fully read without problem, so I think the script is pretty solid other than maybe not accounting for some difference in pdf format that I don't know about.

Here is the actual file:
[PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QsRY8AMrVLqdem2WP4Wjt1j3LX_RXlOR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Some PDFs simply don't contain the information for simple text extraction, i.e. their fonts neither contain actual **ToUnicode** maps nor **Encoding** entries, or the information in either of these structures is wrong. Please share the PDF in question for analysis (a screenshot does not suffice).

Comment: Added a link to the file in google drive.

Comment: and if it is the case that this font does not carry that needed info, is my only route ocr?

Comment: The situation is somewhat weird: The fonts do contain **ToUnicode** maps... but they are empty! They do contain **Encoding** lists but these lists only use pseudostandard names **Uxxxx**. I don't know pdfminer well enough. If it understands those **Uxxxx** names, *removing* the empty **ToUnicode** maps might help.

Comment: thanks for taking a look. I really don't know anything about PDFs, so I'm not sure how I could remove that empty ToUnicode mapping. Any resource you could point me to?

Comment: *"Any resource you could point me to?"* - I'd know how to do that using Java (and iText or PDFBox) or C# (and iText) but I know neither Python nor the Python PDF libraries well enough for that.